# Viewpager pages with different layouts but same fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

Using a ViewPager, I'm working on a guide that tells the user how to use my app.

This is how i currently add/setup the pages:

```
    ...
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Guide_fragment();
        case 1:
            return new Guide_fragment_2();

        case 2,3,4 etc.

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
            ...
```

But this way I have to have a fragment class for each page, and since the pages are only images and text, I figured that it might not be necessary.

Is there a way I can just use the same fragment class for all pages and then just assign a different layouts to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can just use the same fragment class for all pages and then just assign a different layouts to it?

Sure. Pass data into the fragment indicating what to display, typically via the factory pattern:

- Create a static `newInstance()` method that takes the data you might ordinarily pass to the fragment constructor
- `newInstance()` takes those parameters, puts them in a `Bundle`, and attaches the `Bundle` to a newly-constructed instance of your fragment via `setArguments()`
- Your fragment, when it needs this data, calls `getArguments()` to retrieve the `Bundle`

This ensures that your data will survive configuration changes.

Comment: Great. What about the other way round? Have multiple fragments but all the fragments use the same layout inside the view pager (Case: Layouts for all the fragments are same only the contents it shows changes)? Can I use the same layout file (rootView) for all the fragments (precisely 4) inside the view pager?

Comment: @SrikarReddy: "Can I use the same layout file" -- sure. I am not sure why you would have four fragment classes for this, versus doing something else (e.g., single fragment class with four different presenter implementations). But, one fragment does not care what resources are used by another fragment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, It's just one fragment class. Based on the argument (which is received from the newInstance method), I made four network calls to receive different data and populated the layout.

Comment: @SrikarReddy: That is perfectly fine. [My book's](https://commonsware.com/Android) app has a `ViewPager` with a couple hundreds pages, one per book chapter, and each is an instance of the same fragment class, just with different data.