# Use same fragment in ViewPager but fragment will have different layout each time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to keep my application thin.

**Problem:** I would like to reuse my `Fragment` class code to create 3 different instances in the `ViewPager` which will have 3 pages. Each `Fragment` will have a different `ImageView` or background `Drawable`. What are best practices regarding this? I noticed that using factory methods like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744333/viewpager-pages-with-different-layouts-but-same-fragment-class) seem to be good, any other alternatives?

I have one `Fragment` which has the following methods:

**Fragment.java**

```
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    FragmentTutorial f = new FragmentTutorial();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
    return root;
}
```

I have a ViewPagerAdapter class which has the following methods:

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new FragmentTutorial().newInstance(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalPage;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I've found is the "best" way to do it (in my opinion, of course) is to do the following:

- Have the fragment contain methods to set the customizable data (background, text, etc)

  - Note: Be careful of trying to load the data in when first creating the fragment. You may be able to set the data before `onCreateView()` even runs, or at other times it may run after onCreateView(). I personally use a boolean to check if the data has been set. Inside `onCreateView()` [or `onActivityCreated()`], I check if the data has been set already. If it has, load in the data. Alternatively, while setting the data, I check if the views have been created/cached already. This is done by simply having variables to cache the data, say `private ImageView mBackgroundView`. If the view is not null, then I safely set the data on the views.
  - The above is also an alternative to using newInstance, although both methods work pretty well. However, for more flexibility, I only use newInstance if a) the data is already known before the fragment has to be inserted and b) the data doesn't need to change according to input from elsewhere much.
- Let the ViewPager handle all the data

  - Pass in all the data - a list of ImageViews, a array of Strings, define where all the data is in Resources, etc - at the very beginning [say, in the constructor]
  - Have the ViewPager create an ArrayList of the fragments- set up each fragment as early as possible (say when first getting all the data) and add it to the list
  - Let `getCount()` just use the size of the list
  - Let `getItem()` just get the item in the list at the position

    - Note: If you have any dynamic data, set it up in the getItem() method. Furthermore, you can always add more data+fragments during runtime as well [just notify the adapter that the dataset has been changed]

Essentially, the fragment is like a simple servant- it does simply the least work necessary. If it doesn't have to handle choosing the data, all the better. It'll thus be far more flexible. Just give methods to set the data/views appropriately on the fragment. Now, the ArrayAdapter can do all the grimy hard work with managing the data and giving it to the appropriate fragment. Take advantage of that.

Now, note that this is assuming you want to use a single layout but want to change different aspects of that layout (texts, background, etc). If you want to make a master fragment class that can use any sort of defined layout, you can but note that it decreases the runtime flexibility (how can you change the text or background to something you get from the internet? You simply can't if you only can define and choose from pre-set layouts).

Either way, the ArrayAdapter should take care of all the different data while the fragment simply does as it's designed to do, in a more flexible manner preferably.

**Edit:**
Here is the project where I most recently implemented this sort of pattern. Note that it has far more to it, so I'll replace it with some not-so-pseudo pseudo-code in the morning/afternoon.

- [ViewPager](https://github.com/jawadmn/OneCoolThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/umich/engin/cm/onecoolthing/CoolThings/CoolThingsPagerAdapter.java) [a bit sloppy with all the different things I was trying to do, including extending from a FragmentStatePagerAdapter without actually using any of the specific features of a StatePagerAdapter. In other words, I still need to work on the lifecycle implementations everywhere]
- [Fragment](https://github.com/jawadmn/OneCoolThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/umich/engin/cm/onecoolthing/CoolThings/CoolThingFrag.java) [Also may be a bit sloppy but shows the pattern still]
- The [object](https://github.com/jawadmn/OneCoolThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/umich/engin/cm/onecoolthing/CoolThings/OneCoolFeedFrag.java) (actually another fragment) that uses the ViewPager [it's actually a "VerticalViewpager" from a library, but other than the animations and direction to change the current fragment, it's exactly the same- particularly code-wise]

**Edit2:**
Here is a more (if overly) simplified example of the pattern described above.

*Disclaimer: The following code has absolutely no lifecycle management implementations and is older code that has been untouched since around August '14*

- Fragment simply allows the user of the fragment to set the background color and the text of the single TextView

  - [Link to BaseFragment](https://github.com/jawadmn/MDSandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/MDstudios/mdsandbox/BaseFragment.java)
  - [Link to layout file](https://github.com/jawadmn/MDSandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_base.xml)
- The adapter creates three instances of the fragment and sets the background color and text of each. Each fragment's text, color, and total fragments is hard coded.

  - [Link to Activity+adapter](https://github.com/jawadmn/MDSandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/MDstudios/mdsandbox/SlideTabActivity.java)
  - [Link to layout file](https://github.com/jawadmn/MDSandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_slide_tab.xml)

Now, here are the exact relevant portions of the code:

### BaseFragment

```
// Note: Found out later can extend normal Fragments but must use v13 adapter
public class BaseFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    FrameLayout mMainLayout; // The parent layout
    int mNewColor = 0; // The new bg color, set from activity
    String mNewText = ""; // The new text, set from activity
    TextView mMainText;  // The only textview in this fragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the fragment's layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base,container,false);
        // Save the textview for further editing
        mMainText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // Save the framelayout to change background color later
        mMainLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // If there is new text or color assigned, set em
        if(mNewText != ""){
            mMainText.setText(mNewText);
        }
        if(mNewColor != 0){
            mMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(mNewColor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    // Simply indicate to change the text of the fragment
    public void changeText(String newText){
        mNewText=newText;
    }

    // Simply indicate to change the background color of the fragment
    public void changeBG(int color) {
        // If no color was passed, then set background to white
        if(color == 0)
        {
            mNewColor=getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        }
        // else set the color to what was passed in
        else{
            mNewColor=color;
        }
    }
}
```

### MyAdapter

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    // Three simple fragments
    BaseFragment fragA;
    BaseFragment fragB;
    BaseFragment fragC;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setFragments(Context c){

        // Set up the simple base fragments
        fragA = new BaseFragment();
        fragB = new BaseFragment();
        fragC = new BaseFragment();

        Resources res = c.getResources();

        fragA.changeText("This is Fragment A!");
        fragB.changeText("This is Fragment B!");
        fragC.changeText("This is Fragment C!");

        fragA.changeBG(res.getColor(R.color.dev_blue));
        fragB.changeBG(res.getColor(R.color.dev_green));
        fragC.changeBG(res.getColor(R.color.dev_orange));

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO: Make this more efficient, use a list or such, also comment more
        Fragment frag = null;
        if(position == 0){
            frag = fragA;
        }
        else if(position == 1){
            frag = fragB;
        }
        else if(position == 2){
            frag = fragC;
        }

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need an example, I can give a quick link to my current project on GitHub, although it may have a bit too many other processes happening in the adapter [lazy loading images and other data, particularly] to make much sense via a simple glance.

Comment: Also, I can create some not-so-pseudo pseudo-code, if that would help clarify for you. I should have a "base" fragment class still lying around to help out along with maybe an ArrayAdapter for it in my git history. The fragment can simply be set to use any background color and/or use any text.

Comment: That would be awesome if you link me

Comment: Btw your explanation was extremely helpful, some not-so-pseudo pseudo code would make this answer complete

Comment: I added the links to my code, but take note that the lifecycle implementations are still very lacking. Also, I think this was the first time I implemented a system like this with a ViewPager but it's the one I most remember so I included it quickly for now. It's 1:57 AM at the moment and I need to wake up around 9-10 AM, so I'll try to get back to this as soon as possible in the morning/afternoon.

Comment: @AndyRoid: Added in a not-so-pseudo pseudo code example, although I found out that I actually did do a simpler example around August. In the end, I linked to the GitHub pages each example was in as well, and the other bright side is that the code is tested to work for sure. Hope it helps~

Comment: I also have a question regarding the BaseFragment, should I setup a newInstance() method inside the BaseFragment? That wasn't included in your pseudo-code (you mentioned lifecycle implementation wasn't included) but do you think that is a good idea, because these fragments would not have communication to the rest of the application.

Comment: Yup, for this exact example, newInstance() would be a good idea with the BaseFragments. The data is only set once (at the beginning) and the fragments never have to communicate with anything else. However, as a side note, you can still have fragments communicate with other portions, but that would change the fragment class's flexibility. Ie, if a fragment had to communicate with its "parent" (Activity or a parent fragment) through an interface, you can have that happen. You just have to make sure to define an instance of that interface beforehand- which can be used with newInstance().

Comment: Just to be extra clear: I mean, don't try to use newInstance() [by only itself] if you **have** to *receive* data from outside the fragment, but you don't have/want that specific feature built into the fragment. For example, I have to set the background and title for the first Edit's fragment. However, I get that data later on via lazy loading. newInstance() wouldn't really work then [by itself], as I get the data later on but I still want to show the fragment before receiving the data (with a loading screen, in this case).

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to set a different imageview for each newInstance() of fragment at position 0, 1, and 2. What do you think the best way to do that would be. Can you include that in your answer? I like the idea of a base fragment, and maybe implementing an inteface? What do you think? Maybe using the onPageChangeListener instead??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66527/discussion-between-mdragon00-and-andyroid).

Comment: Really appreciate the code, however a bit curious why this was not upvoted more. I am basically using Firebase to update data periodically, and I want my ViewPager to display the dynamic data that I add to Firebase (the ViewPager uses the Firebase listener to update the data).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass some sort of id along with `newInstance()` while creating instance. And according to that id you can use `if..else` to choose layout file.

See my reference code below:

```
int id;
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context, int id) {
FragmentTutorial f = new FragmentTutorial();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
this.id = id;
return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(id == 1)
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
else
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
return root;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the above code is that you cannot declare this.id = id inside a static method

Comment: It is just a reference code, you need to implement your business logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just introduce fields to the Fragment class to account for the variances in background, etc. and add them to its constructor? Then in `getItem` instantiate the Fragment class with different values depending on the value of `position`.